# Получаю ошибку DeprecationWarning: desired_capabilities has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object

Tags: python, selenium, test-automation, pytest, warning

При прогоне автотестов выскакивает предупреждение:
`DeprecationWarning: desired_capabilities has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object`
вроде ничего страшного, но глаза мозолит, как от этого избавится?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вот что я поменял

Что было

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

caps = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME
caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "eager"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), desired_capabilities=caps)
```

Что стало

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.set_capability("pageLoadStrategy", "eager")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
```